CRON - "Command not found" despite PATH being set
I have a small bash script (script.sh) I am trying to run on a schedule using cron. Like so:
#!/bin/bash
lsof -cq -au $(whoami) -t | xargs kill -9

Works perfectly fine when run directly in the shell (bash), i.e. ./script.sh kills all processes under q command for current user.
However, when I try to schedule using cron, not so much anymore.
I came across some answers on the platform suggesting to specify the PATH variable at the top of the cron file, which I have done.
PATH=/usr/sbin/lsof:/bin/xargs:/bin/kill:/bin/whoami:
53 6 * * 1-5 /path/to/script.sh

Regardless, I still get the following output:
...
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/sbin/lsof:/bin/xargs:/bin/kill:/bin/whoami:>
...
~/script.sh: line 2: xargs: command not found
~/script.sh: line 2: whoami: command not found
~/script.sh: line 2: lsof: command not found

What am I missing?
Thanks

Try adding to $PATH only the parent dirs: PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

PATH is a list of directories where your shell can find commands, it's not a list of files to be called as commands. See PATH in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Variables.

Voting to close as a typo, but good job on posting an easily diagnosed problem. You included all the necessary information to debug the problem. Keep posting!

Thanks everyone. Could swear I'd done that as part of my debug efforts but perhaps some silly typo. Closing this.
